# Реализовать обмен данными между игроками unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Уважаемые форумчане, помогите определиться с тем, как написать скрипт для обмена информацией между пользователями. Объясню в чем суть: пишу игрулю, в которой игроку наугад падают карточки, он выкладывает их на стол, и если одна карта бьет другую, ему записываются очки. В итоге, после окончания матча побеждает игрок с наибольшим количеством очков. Проблема заключается в том, что моих знаний хватает лишь на написание скрипта для одного игрока, то есть, карты ему выдаются и он может их выбросить, а как реализовать обмен между игроками - не понимаю. При всем этом каждый игрок должен видеть свою панель и аватар с характеристиками других игроков как на картинке во вложении. Было бы здорово, если бы попутно вы покидали мануалы или живые примеры того, как реализуется "локальный мультиплеер" в таких играх, то есть, чтобы поиграть с друзьями и один человек-host возьмет на себя обязанность держать сервер с игрой.[image: Вложение]

Comment: Могу дать ссылки на видео - [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCRY2PvU1uw), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C4NNPI8VUM), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJgkjduXRBU), [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKus7NfjLk4)